# 403 only on my machine - Angular 2 & Tomcat 8.5

Tags: angular, http, tomcat, cors, preflight

So Im working on a group project and all of us have our git branches pushed to the head of master. Meaning we all are running identical code. When we go to the landing page of our project, our `ngOnInit()` sends a get request with a header that contains a custom header, right?

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    let sessionID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-data')).JSESSIONID;
    headers.append('JSESSIONID', sessionID);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'JSESSIONID');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200/webplayer');
  }

ngOnInit() {
    let header = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(header);
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header, params: params             });

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/sample-webapp/rest/music/landingPage', options)
    .subscribe(data => this.popularArtists = JSON.parse(data["_body"]).popularArtists);
```

Seems harmless, my teammates get a 200 as a response, but I get this message:

[image: 403 Preflight Error Message]

Btw this request works with postman on my machine so it's leading me to think that this *must* have something to do with the browser (same issues for Safari, Chrome, and Firefox).

So we have done everything from adding additional fields to the server's web.xml, to adding options annotations, to deleting cookies. I really want to know what it's not working solely on my machine. I might have missed something in previous steps so please let me know what could work. I can also add my web.xml and other stuff upon request.

BACKEND CORS FILTER:

```
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeaderString("origin"));
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", request.getHeaderString("access-control-request-headers"));
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "JSESSIONID");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", request.getHeaderString("access-control-request-method"));
```

Comment: Does it work on other developer machines?

Comment: Yes, it does work on other teammate's browsers and backend

Comment: And what are your CORS options? Are you running any middleware that might strip the headers?

Comment: I mean we included the headers that are in the request headers. I have, added the backend headers at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Additionally, this call doesn't hit the backend server

Comment: update, we narrowed it down to the fact that it's a custom header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we figured it out and changed the header function to this:

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    let sessionID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user-data')).JSESSIONID;
    headers.append('JSESSIONID', sessionID);
}
```

and it worked. If someone can tell me why, I would appreciate it.